# Spring boot web application integration tests suite

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I have a bunch of integrations tests containing

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootApp.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
```

The problem i have is the application gets started and stopped for every test class. Is there anyway i can start the application once, run all the integration tests and stop?

Comment: what do you mean with "gets started and stopped for every test class"?

Comment: How the hell is this not default behaviour?

Comment: I think that is the default behavior. How are you running the integration tests? Gradle? Maven? IDE?

Comment: Create one or more test `Suite` and add all integration tests into it by `@Suite.SuiteClasses({...})` annotation